# "Traversing DOM" nextSibling property not working. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, dom, siblings

The JS nextSibling property does not work for me.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>DOCUMENT OBJECT MODEL</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="sameClass" id="one">first list item</li>
            <li class="sameClass" id="two">second list item</li>
            <li class="sameClass" id="three">third list item</li>
            <li class="sameClass" id="four">fourth list item</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="getValues"></div>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
li.sameClass{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
li.targetClass{
    background-color:orange;
    color:red;
}
```

JS:

```
var element = document.getElementById("one").nextSibling;
element.className = "targetClass";
```

This code should change the appearance of the second list item with `id="two"` by changing its className to "targetClass". That doesn't work and `document.querySelector("#one")` doesn't work either.

What can be the problem?

Comment: The next sibling of the node with id `one` is a text node.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `nextSibling`, use `nextElementSibling`.

`nextSibling` - Finds the next sibling, even if it's not an element (ie. text node)

`nextElementSibling` - Finds next sibling that IS an element.

Comment: that works.... Thnx.. But can you also explain?

Comment: Okay, got it. Thnx for the help.